# How do I avoid duplicate fields in Json request payload ? I'm using Apache Camel with REST

Tags: rest, apache-camel, json-deserialization, jsonparser, spring-camel

I wanted to parse json request by identifying duplicate fields in the request body. E.g. Assume I have below request.

```
`"employee": {
      "name": "abc",
      "name": "xyz",
      "id": "6754",
      "title": "supervisor",
}`
```

The employee request above has duplicate **name** field. ideally during json validation/parsing the second duplicate field takes precedence over first but I want to invalidate this kind of json request. How do I achieve this in Camel REST. Below is the approach that I tried but nothing worked. In myorg.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder, I tried configuring DataFormatProperty to use **DeserializationFeature** **FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY** but its not failing. How do I fail the request for invalid json request which has duplicate fields.?

```
`@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
         restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).component("servlet")
           .jsonDataFormat(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION.name())
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.enableFeatures",
                        "FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS,USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS,FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY"
                                + ",FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE,"
                                + JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION.name())
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS").enableCORS(true)`
```

Answer (score 0):

This may come from the fact that **Camel is using XStream as default JSON library** (see [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/json.html)).
Did you already try to force the use of Jackson library ?

Comment: How do I force Jackson library? If XStream is the default JSON library, then how can I avoid duplicate fields? can you share the code snippet for validating duplicate fields?